# GPG key could not be added by apt-key on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt, apt-key

I can not add the gpg key for apt repository into keychain. But I can add it through the gpg --import

When I try to add it with apt-key add, it just doesn't appear there, and I get no obvious error:

curl -sSL https://deb.********.com/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -

```
gpg: key 8D81803C0EBFCD88: "Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>" not changed
gpg: key 7C3D57159FC2F927: "InfluxData Package Signing Key <support@influxdata.com>" not changed
gpg: key 1285491434D8786F: "Dell Inc., PGRE 2012 (PG Release Engineering Build Group 2012) <PG_Release_Engineering@Dell.com>" not changed
gpg: key D8FF8E1F7DF8B07E: doesn't match our copy
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: Total number processed: 8
gpg:       skipped new keys: 4
gpg:              unchanged: 3
```

Then I check the key with apt-key list, and it is still not there. I noticed this behavior, when my ansible playbook stopped working (because it can't add the key with apt_key module). Any thoughts ?